# What is "Connected Client Count" on Azure IoT Edge dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I need to know how to get "Connected Client Count" from API rest or go SDK, but I did not find any reference of what does it really means. From where "Connected Client Count" comes?

My guess:
The "Connected Client Count" is calculating doing the following:

- Get the device list from API.
- For one of these devices get the modules from API
- Now it could return many modules depending on your architecture, so in my case it will ignores agent and hub modules, considering just other nodeRed modules as a real client. If the client (nodeRed module) *connectionStatus == connected* so this is a valid client connect and should return +1.

I would be very glad for an explanation of this or some doc references.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Connected Client Count" that you find in the Azure Portal reflects the amount of modules and/or devices that are currently connected to your edgeHub. It gets these values from the reported properties in the Module Twin of your edgeHub module. If you take a look in the Module Twin you will find something similar to this in the reported properties:

```json
"reported": {
      "schemaVersion": "1.0",
      "version": {
        "version": "1.0.10.1",
        "build": "36502453",
        "commit": "3b3dfcc099921bc2e4632105b49df551b1c5211c0"
      },
      "lastDesiredVersion": 39,
      "lastDesiredStatus": {
        "code": 200,
        "description": ""
      },
      "clients": {
        "device-name/SomeModule": {
          "status": "Connected",
          "lastConnectedTimeUtc": "2020-11-26T10:10:17.6134347Z"
        },
        "device-name/SomeOtherModule": {
          "status": "Connected",
          "lastConnectedTimeUtc": "2020-11-26T10:10:17.6278367Z"
        }
      },
```

You can find out more on the reported properties of this module [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-edgeagent-edgehub?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-2018-06)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer :)